# Tower law and iterated expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let's take 3 random variables $X,Y,Z$ on the same probability space (or associated with the same experiment), then applying the tower law in an iterative fashion we get:

$$ E[X] = E_Y[E_{X|Y}[X|Y]] = E_Y\left[E_{Z|Y
}\left[E_{X|Y,Z}\left[X|Y,Z\right]|Y\right]\right] $$
where I specified the pdfs on which we integrate below the expectation $(E)$ symbol. Precisely, we have that
$$ E_{X|Y}[X|Y] = E_{Z|Y}\left[E_{X|Y,Z}\left[X|Y,Z\right]|Y\right] $$

However, if I am not mistaken, the above implies that the following is not true:

$$ E[E[X|Y]|Z] = E[E[X|Y,Z]] $$

I have some difficulty in understanding why, any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not true in general, because the left-hand side is a random variable and the right-hand side is a number. Suppose $X=Y=Z$ then,
$$E(E(X|Y)|Z) = E(E(X|X)|X) = E(X|X) = X$$
but,
$$E(E(X|Y,Z)) = E(E(X|X)) = E(X)$$
which are not equal so long as $X$ is not degenerate.

Comment: Jose Avilez: Thanks a lot for your answer and clear explanation. Just a question, the integration pdfs of $E(E(X|Y)|Z)$ would be: 
$$E_{Y|Z}(E_{X|Y}(X|Y)|Z)$$
and of $E(E(X|Y,Z))$ would be: 
$$ E_{Y,Z}(E_{X|Y,Z}(X|Y,Z))$$ ?

Comment: @BMBE that looks right to me